# Calculate the sum grouped by 2 other columns

Tags: dax

Please I really need your help on this, Hello,

I need to create a measure using DAX that has the sum of the qty, I should take the max date of the table that is between two other dates (Date Slicer) based on the column name, For example, if the selected date of the slicer is between  24/6/2020 and 20/3/2021, I need to calculate the total (sum of the qty of each name 'column' where it's date is the max date that is less then the max selected date

[image]
So as you can see in the figure the total should be 50+129+3(For that selected date)

Answer (score 0):

```
Quantity = 
VAR _maxdate =
    MAX ( 'Date Table'[Date] )
RETURN
    SUM ( CALCULATE([Qty], 'Fact Table'[Date] <= _maxdate )
```

The [CALCULATE](https://dax.guide/calculate/) function in DAX is very powerful. Essentially, you can pass filter criteria into it to create aggregations. In this case, *it sounds* like you want to sum [Qty] when the date is < the max date.

Since your table visuals aren't automatically updating, you also may not be [implementing a date table correctly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/model-date-tables).

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this won't give me the right answer, For example for The B 'Name' I should take only 120 and not the 5 because 20/22021 is bigger then 30/1/2021

Comment: Your data model and requirements aren't clear to me. I don't see "120" anywhere in your screenshot. Maybe someone else that comes along will be able to interpret it. The maximum date you have on your date slider is March 20, 2021.  If your date slider comes from a date table, it's going to load March 20, 2021 into VAR _maxdate. Then, it will only sum rows that have a [Date] value <= March 20, 2021.

Comment: sorry I mean 129, yes it will sum all rows where the date is  <= March 20, 2021. but I need to take the qty of each 'name' that corresponds to the max date of that name which is  <= March 20, 2021 That's why the Total should be 129+50+3 the 5 of the B will not be calculated even it's date is   <= March 20, 2021 but 30/1/2021 the bigger date for B when date  <= March 20, 2021.